# Mongoose push end edit

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i have a problem updating field and push object on the same document in one action.
this is my simple schema looks like

```
var Schema = new schema({
    shopName: String,
    address: String
    products: [productSchema]
}) 

var productSchema = new schema({
    productName: String,
    ingredients: String,
    item: {
        qty: {type: Number, default: 0},
        carted: [
            {
                cartId: String, 
                timestamp: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

the illustration is when i add cart for a product, then i will subtract the product quantity with quantity order, and also push cart info to the 'carted' array field.

i've found that `"$inc": {"products.$.item.qty": -req.body.orderQty}` can subtract the quantity, but it only runs on `findOneAndUpdate` query.

so, is there an efficient way to handle that case?

Answer (score 0):

ok just tried this, and solved my problem

```
productModel.update({'products._id' : productID}, 
                    {
                        "$inc": {"products.$.item.qty": -req.body.cartQty}, 
                        "$push": {"products.$.item.carted": {cartId: req.body.cartId, qty: req.body.cartQty}}
                    },function(err, docs){
                        if (err){
                            console.log(err)
                        }else{
                            console.log(docs)
                        }
                    })
```